# Return the built Enum to JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot, enums, jackson

I have an object and an enum for it. When I give away an object, I want my enum inside the object to be displayed as an object with the name and value attributes without using DTO, or to be partially used. I want json to build this object itself (enum with name and value), and I give only the object in which this enum is contained.

```
public enum MyType {
TT("Time Tu"), TD("Time dust");

MyType(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

private String value;

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}
```

Here is the DTO, it may be necessary (get/set/constructor auto generated by Intellij Idea)

```
public class MyTypeWrapper {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}

@Entity
public class MyObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    private String number;
    ........
    private MyType myType;
    ........
}
```

Perhaps serialization/deserialization is needed? How to do it?

It should go something like this:

```
{
   .....
   myType: {
   "name: "TT",
   "value: "TD"
},
   .....
}
```

Perhaps this is a piece of the solution? But I'm not sure that it will work, and it's not clear how to serialize

```
public enum MyType {
......
@JsonValue
private MyTypeWrapper getWrapper()
return new MyTypeWrapper(this.name, this.value)
}
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be the solution

```
public enum MyType {
......
@JsonValue
private MyTypeWrapper getWrapper()
return new MyTypeWrapper(this.name, this.value)
}
......
}
```